# Extracting Data from a Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

For my school project, I need the data on this website:
https://services2.hdb.gov.sg/web/fi10/emap.html
Specifically, I need the longitude and latitude, address, flat type and the number of units of the flat type in csv or excel format so that I can do some spatial analysis.

How do I create an automated process to get all the data from the website and not clicking all the individual buildings?

Appreciate any assistance on this. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Goombah unfortunately, I dont have any coding experience, so I do not know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

I got a look at the network traffic when this site is querying it's data. There you can find the XHR-Requests where also the streetname and other things are written down. You may use this to collect your data.

Comment: I do not have any coding experience, how can I do that?